# Doctrine error to create database : Access denied for user

Tags: database, doctrine, symfony

i tried to create a new database in Doctrine, with `php app/console doctrine:database:create` but i got an error : i fixed it thanks to this  [website](http://www.iamseree.com/application-development/doctrine-create-database-error-no-such-file-or-directory)

now i've got a second error, but i can't find any solution :

afther this :

`pc11:Symfony Paul$ php app/console doctrine:database:create`

i've got this error :

> Could not create database for connection named symfony
>   SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

i tried without "symfony" but it did not work :
`pc11:~ Paul$ php app/console doctrine:database:create

Could not open input file: app/console`

Would you know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You're probably missing database configuration, it tries to connect to MySQL as the user `root` without a password and fails to get the permission to create the database.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson : thanks! it works, i added "root" as the password in `app/config/parameters.ini` , and it works fine. Can you post an official answer so that i check your answer? thanks again Joachim! (ps: how stupid it is to put a -1, Joachim's answer helped me a lot.) Cheers man!

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson : hello Joachim, can you put a +1 for me?

Comment: How did you fix first problem? I have got same problem like your first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably missing database configuration, it tries to connect to MySQL *as the user `root` without a password* and fails to get the permission to create the database.

Check your `parameters.ini` for settings related to the database connection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the password for root@localhost to be blank. There are two ways:

```
The MySQL SET PASSWORD command:

SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('');

Using the command-line mysqladmin tool:

mysqladmin -u root -pCURRENTPASSWORD password ''
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

This worked for me on Mac OS X with MAMP (or MAMP Pro).

Add **database.unix_socket** in **app/config/parameters.xml**

```
parameters:
    database.driver:        pdo_mysql
    database.host:          localhost
    database.port:          8888
    database.name:          my-database-name
    database.user:          root
    database.password:      root
    database.unix_socket:   /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Add **unix_socket** in **app/config/config.xml**

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # ...
        unix_socket: "%database.unix_socket%"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

If you want to try with php you have to change `app/console`  to `bin/console`

[image]